# Como alterar o atributo "src" de uma tag <script> usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-eventos

Quero a partir de um mesmo `index.html` poder mudar seu conteúdo usando dois arquivos `.js` diferentes. Resumindo, quero alterar o `.js` sem mudar de página `html`, Tipo:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="texto" onclick="function(){ dcoument.querrySelector('#teste').src = 'teste2.js'">Teste</button>
        <script id="teste"  src="teste1.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Isso é possével, ou algo do tipo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas alterando o `src` da tag não irá carregar o novo script na memória ou executá-lo, ou seja, não causará nenhum efeito. E mesmo depois de carregar o script `teste1.js` você não conseguirá apagá-lo da memória enquanto a página estiver aberta.

O que você poderia fazer é criar de forma dinâmica uma nova tag `script` com o `teste2.js`. Aí sim o código de `teste2.js` será carregado na memória. Adicione a nova tag com `.createElement()` e `.appendChild()`:

```
<button id="texto" onclick="var scr = document.createElement('script');
   scr.src = 'teste2.js'; document.body.appendChild(scr)">Teste</button>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado XD

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de `document.querySelector('#teste')`, você colocou `dcoument.querrySelector('#teste')`

```
<img src="exemplo.png">
<button type="button">Mudar imagem</button>

<script>
    const button = document.querySelector('button')

    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        const imagem = document.querySelector('img')
        imagem.src = 'exemplo2.png'

        event.preventDefault()
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para você alterar o atributo de uma tag *script*, você precisar usar o método **setAttribute**, passando como parâmetro o atributo desejado e o valor.

```
const script = document.querySelector('script');
script.setAttribute('src', 'file.example.js');
```